# Define a custom named list in Excel to be used for data-validation

Tags: excel

I am trying to set up a drop-down menu in Excel using a named list, but I would like to write the entries for the named variable myself.

So, say I define a named list (call it TestVar) as (using the Name manager)

```
={"A","B"}
```

(alternatively with a semi-colon to create a column), I cannot use it for data validation. So if I under data validation choose the "list" option, and write

```
=TestVar
```

as the source, I get the "The Source currently evaluates to an error." message.

I don't understand why TestVar isnt't a valid list, as it works with both the INDEX-function, as well as array formulas.

Also, I know that I could write

```
A,B
```

as the source when setting up my data-validation, and that gives me the behaviour I want, but I think it makes more sense to have it defined as a named list, in case one needs to append to the list at some point in the future, and the list is referenced multiple times in the document.

Edit:

Forgot to mention that I use Excel 2013.

Comment: Is this still known to be an issue in Excel 365? I'm seeing the same weird behaviour today i.e. I can define a Name as ={"A","B"}, for example, and if I refer to that Name in a cell it correctly Spills to an array/list. But Data Validation cannot use it unless the Name is on a block of cells ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you record a macro you'll see that the list is just a string of values separated by commas. This will do what you want:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ValidationFormula As String

ValidationFormula = "1,2"
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=ValidationFormula
End With
End Sub
```

EDIT:

To set a Data Validation's source to an Excel Name, that Name needs to point to a Named Range. I don't know of a way to have it just refer to a name that's set up like `"1,2` or `=1,2`.

Below I defined a named range ValidationList that refers to `C2:C5`. Then in A2 I opened the Data Validation dialog and pointed to that named range:

[image]

Note that if you do it this way, you'll want it to be a [dynamic named range](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287). Also see this [Chandoo post](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/09/13/dynamic-data-validation-excel/).

Comment: Hmm, yeah I guess it does, but is there no way to do this without macros? That's kinda stupid. Also, it doesn't really solve the initial problem, as you will need to re-run the macro on everywhere the list is used for validation if it is ever update. (I guess one can write a macro which does that, but I'd still say the behaviour is unsatisfactory)

Comment: I'm confused. You want to use a variable, i.e., `TestVar`, but without using VBA? Please explain.

Comment: Ah, might not have used the correct terminology, terribly sorry. I basically want to define a name using the built in name manager, but write its entries by hand. Edit: updated the post and changed "named variable" to "named list"

Comment: So, are you saying that it is not possible to use a name for data validation without the name referring to somewhere in the document? So I cannot define a name as a comma separated list (only stored in the name manager, not referring to cells), and use that for data validation?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying. From [Excel's help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.validation_properties.aspx): "Formula1 - Returns the value or expression associated with the conditional format or data validation. Can be a constant value, a string value, a cell reference, or a formula. Read-only String."

Comment: So, one cannot represent the contents of a cell inside a formula in excel? Example, say I fill A1 to A3 with 1,2,3, will then writing {1,2,3} not be equivalent with A1:A3? It seems so in all excel functions I have tried (SUM, INDEX, ...), the only place it doesn't seem to work is in data validation, which is why I posted this question.

Comment: I'm going to say "no" again. There is a `Custom` option in Data Validation's type dropdown, which allows you to enter a formula, but if you enter the contents of a single cell, as far as I know, it treats the entire contents as the single allowed value. The other shortcoming is that the Custom type doesn't show a dropdown. I'm curious, why not just use a range, as is common practice? It seems easier for users and it works. I'm not sure what advantage you see in requiring a use to edit a single cell.

Comment: Okai. Well, I just wanted to completely hide the information from the user, as it wasn't suppose to be editable, but I still wanted it to be easily managed. Problem is that the document is suppose to go up on sharepoint at some point, and using the Office 365 WebApp, one cannot make use of stuff like protected (and hidden cells), so storing it in a name would in theory hide it. Also, I am not one who uses Excel a lot, and being more comfortable with high level programming languages, variables (or aliases and so on) makes more sense to me than array entries.

Comment: @pnuts, only if you want it to offer a list of choices, and not the word "ValidationList" :). Good catch. I'll come back later and fix it.